# neo4j node query dismatch

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 1.9.4.

Please consider the following two queries :

1. `start z=node(*) where z._type! = 'aaa' return count(z);`
2. `start z=node(*) match z-[r?]-() where z._type! = 'aaa' return count(z), count(r);`

Shouldn't the result of "count(z)" be the same for both of the two queries?

But I got a result of 2 much larger than the result of 1.

Is this a neo4j bug or is there something wrong with the queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, because when there are nodes with several relationships, `z-[r?]-()` will return several results and thus when returning `count(z)` you will have duplicate values.

try to return `count(DISTINCT z)`

Comment: isn't it more intuitive to think that "count(z)" means to count distinct nodes than the to count the records in the result set? anyway, my own mistake.

Comment: this has something to do with the aggregation function, i bet similar behavior would be found in SQL dbs, too.

Comment: you are right. i thought aggregation functions in SQL dbs is based on the concepts of rows and fields. So in neo4j , intuitively (but mistakenly) aggregations should be based on the returned returned elements such as nodes, relationships , properties or function results. Never thought it's still in rows and "field"s.